# Hierarchical tree structure - Remove independent rows

Tags: php, sql, tree, postgresql-9.2

I've got two tables with structure described below:

```
CREATE TABLE products
(
  id integer NOT NULL,
  name text,
  CONSTRAINT pk_first PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);

CREATE TABLE events
(
  id integer NOT NULL,
  parent integer,
  CONSTRAINT pk_second PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);

INSERT INTO events (
  id, parent)
  VALUES (1, 1), (2, 1), (3, 1), (4, 2), (5, 3), (6, 6), (7, 6); 

INSERT INTO products(
            id, name)
    VALUES (1,'A'), (2,'B'),(3,'C'),(4,'D');
```

Now, I have to remove all rows from events table which has no connection to products. By connection I mean join between Id from events and id from products, but there is no foreign key and in events table can be rows that have no equivalent to row in products.

I cannot remove any row that depends on one with connection through parent_id.

Example:

Examining row with id 3 from products table I cannot remove row with id 3 in table events and I cannot remove any of rows with id 1,2,4 and 5 -> because they all depends on 3 through parent_id. But I can remove rows with id 6 and 7 - there is no dependencies.

Any ideas?

Comment: Seems quite similar to http://stackoverflow.com/q/17485914/398670 ...

Comment: no, it's something else, but I've used similar table names.