# Joining two tables with aggregates

Tags: sql, join, postgresql-9.2

I've got two tables described below:

```
CREATE TABLE categories
(
  id integer NOT NULL,
  category integer NOT NULL,
  name text,
  CONSTRAINT kjhfskfew PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);

CREATE TABLE products_
(
  id integer NOT NULL,
  date date,
  id_employee integer,
  CONSTRAINT grh PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
```

Now I have to do report in which I need following information:
categories.category, categories.name (all of them, so string_agg is ok) - could be many assigned to one category and products_.id_employee -> but not with comma as above with category name but the one with newest date assigned (and here is my problem);

I've tried already constructions as:

```
SELECT
  DISTINCT ON (category ) category,
  string_agg(name, ','),
  (SELECT
     id_employee
   FROM products_
   WHERE date = (SELECT
                   max(date)
                 FROM products_
                 WHERE id IN (SELECT
                                id
                              FROM categories
                              WHERE id = c.id)))
FROM categories c
ORDER BY category;
```

But PostgreSQL says that subquery is returning to many rows...
Please help!

EXAMPLE INSERTS:

```
INSERT INTO categories(
            id, category, name)
    VALUES (1,22,'car'),(2,22,'bike'),(3,22,'boat'),(4,33,'soap'),(5,44,'chicken');

INSERT INTO products_(
            id, date, id_employee)
    VALUES (1,'2009-11-09',11),(2,'2010-09-09',2),(3,'2013-01-01',4),(5,'2014-09-01',90);
```

OK, I've solved this problem.
This one works just fine:

```
WITH max_date AS (
    SELECT
      category,
      max(date)             AS date,
      string_agg(name, ',') AS names
    FROM test.products_
      JOIN test.categories c
      USING (id)
    GROUP BY c.category
)
SELECT
  max(id_employee) AS id_employee,
  md.category,
  names
FROM test.products_ p
  LEFT JOIN max_date md
  USING (date)
  LEFT JOIN test.categories
  USING (category)
WHERE p.date = md.date AND p.id IN (SELECT
                                      id
                                    FROM test.categories
                                    WHERE category = md.category)
GROUP BY category, names;
```

Comment: If you get the chance to add some `INSERT` commands for sample data rows and a summary of the results you'd like to see from that sample data that'd help make this sort of thing a lot easier to answer.

Comment: sure, I've just updated my post.

Comment: what do you want to achieve is not clear. Can you explain?

Comment: I need to group rows by category. with every category (there are 3 in this example - 22,33 and 44) I need to show names from categories table, so for category 22 gonna be: 'car','bike' and 'boat'. Third thing is id_employee assigned to id in products_ table -> and ihis id_employee should be max(date) - so the biggest date from all assigned to category from categories. By 22 category should be 4, because date '2013-01-01' is the biggest one.

Comment: I fail so see how categories and products are related. And what is the difference between the `id` and `category` columns in the `categories` table?

Comment: categories and products are related by id - the same column in both tables. It's a foreign key.

Comment: ok, I've got proper query. solution is in my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that `id` is being used to join the two tables, which seems strange to me.

In any case, the base query for the category names is:

```
SELECT c.category, string_agg(c.name, ','),
FROM categories c
group by c.category;
```

The question is:  how to get the most recent name?  This approach uses the `row_number()` function:

```
SELECT c.category, string_agg(c.name, ','), cp.id_employee
FROM categories c left outer join
     (select c.category, c.name, p.id_employee,
             row_number() over (partition by c.category order by date desc) as seqnum
      from categories c left outer join
           products_ p
           on c.id = p.id
     ) cp
     on cp.category = c.category and
        cp.seqnum = 1
group by c.category, cp.id_employee;
```

Comment: "It seems that id is being used to join the two tables, which seems strange to me." - Why is that so?

Comment: @Borys . . . First `id`, when used as a column name, typically refers to an auto-incremented primary key column in a table.  And, that seems to be how it is used here.  The tables are "parallel" because there is a 1-1 relationship between the primary keys; yet they have names ("categories" and "products") that suggest very different entities.  I would expect the primary key in `categories` to be `CategoryId` (or something like that).  And for `products_` to have a foreign key referring to it.

Comment: yes, now I know what you mean. but names of tables was changed and this structure serve a completely different purpose, thats why it could look a bit strange ;)